# recognition:9 GET http://localhost:3000/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, ejs

I am new to web development and making an app using node js and ejs. I was relying on app get and app post for doing everything on my server.js
I need to merge a separate javascript program with the node app. To do this, I made a new ejs file and linked the javascript file in the  tag and I keep getting the above-mentioned error. I have looked around for similar problems but none of the solutions helped me with this error.
Any help is appreciated! thank you!

```
<head>
<script defer src="/public/face-api.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="/public/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the code for viewing ejs:

```
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
  app.set('view engine','ejs');
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  app.use(flash())
```

And I'm rendering the ejs page in my server.js:

```
app.get('/recognition', (req, res) => {
res.render('recognition')

 })
```

The terminal is free of errors. I am getting this error in the browser console as can be seen in the image- [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5XFn.png)
This is the structure of my code. I have put my JS files inside the public folder and ejs files in views. Everything else is outside.
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjNRn.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read this guide so wen can help you more efficent: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to serve the `script.js` via your express app.

include `app.use(express.static('public'));` in your server code

Read more about it: https://expressjs.com/de/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried adding that to server.js but it made no difference :C
I have edited my question and attached a picture of my project structure. Maybe there's something wrong with my structure? Thank you again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @user12506953 Pleas read this and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where does the error message came from ? Browser, Terminal ?

Comment: I am not getting any error in the terminal. I can see that the js files are not loading when I open the console in the browser. I have edited my question again and added the relevant image. Thank you.

Comment: Why are the browser try to loade the file from `example.com/public/...` ? 
Either remove the "public" path in your frontend or change in your server code `app.use(express.static('public'));` to `app.use('public', express.static('public'));`

Comment: @user12506953 dude, no. The HTTP path has nothing to do with the path on your filesystem. Remove the "public" path from your script tag and the browser should able to load the files.

Comment: Thank you, this worked now. I had to make it /public. But it worked. Thank you! You are a life saviour!

Comment: @user12506953 Your welcome. Please upvote my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I did. Thank you :)